# obtaining UINavigationController in an UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

a custom tab bar controller I am using applies the ViewController or UINavigationController like this:   `UIViewController* viewController = [data objectForKey:@"viewController"];`

I dont knw exactly how it works but "viewController" comes out as a UINavigationController. Next, the custom tab bar controller class adds a tag like so, `viewController.view.tag = THE_TAG;`

Retrieving the controller is uses  `UIView* currentView = [self.window viewWithTag:SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG];`

This part is where I get confused because now when I nslog this 
"currentView" I get a UILayout etc... instead of my UINavigationController. I'm assuming it applied the tag to the UIView that contained the nav controller?

How do I reference the UINavigationController within this UIView?

Comment: in my point of view it is bad design if a `UIView` needs to contact any kind of `UIViewController`. It should be the other way round or let them talk via a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In the above what is `THE_TAG`, and can you confirm that it is unique (i.e. not zero, and not matching something being used elsewhere by the same mechanism)?

I'd be pretty wary overusing `tag` since there is no easy way to gaurentee globally unique tags, and when using something like `self.window viewWithTag` you could see just about every view in the app being checked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a *view* and a *viewController* confused.  A UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController.  It is not a subclass of UIView.  UIViewControllers do have a property which is a UIView class.  It is probably this property that you are accessing when you use viewWithTag: .  So maybe, when you use that method, you are not accessing the UINavigationController but the UINavigationController's view property (which is actually something you should probably not be messing with.)